# RStudio - RevoScaleR (Windows)

Tags: r, rstudio, revoscaler

Can this package be used for either (1) RStudio Desktop/Open; and/or (2) RStudio Server (also using SQL Server 2017 Enterprise)?

I'm primarily interested in RStudio Desktop, however can't appear to find anything online after about one hour of research.

When attempting to install the package in RStudio Desktop, I receive the error message:

```
install.packages("RevoScaleR",dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Harvey/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RevoScaleR’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the R version of 3.5.0. However, [RevoScaleR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/revoscaler/revoscaler) is built on R 3.4.3. You can install any version before 3.4.3 and install the package again. Note that you need Microsoft R Client to be installed and this path can be given to RStudio. Look for the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-client/what-is-microsoft-r-client).

RStudio has a feature to change the version of R without uninstalling your current version. After installing the desired R version, you can go to Tools -> Global Options to change your version.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I was slightly surprised by the error message suggesting that: Does this mean RevoScaleR isn't compatible at all going into the future/is now somewhat deprecated?  Considering use for the long-term for a group of R users across multiple devices.

Comment: When I use 3.4.3, same error message expect now says 'not available for 3.4.3'.  Is the issue actually because I'm using RStudio?

Comment: @theemperor: You are right. You need Microsoft R Client to access it. You can provide R Client path into your rstudio to fix this issue. Here is the documentation of installing R Client and setting up with RStudio. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-client/what-is-microsoft-r-client

Comment: That's great, thanks.  Looking into installing this.  Closing question: Is RevoScaleR usable/compatible with R GUI/base R?

Comment: I believe R Client has the base R functionalities as well.

Comment: As in, is it possible to use RevoScaleR only in base R (in a base R-only solution)?

Comment: Im sure this can be used with just the base R solution. Did you get a chance to fix this issue? if so, can you please mark it as answer?